# Implementing Cloud Backup in Android Java App Using Google Drive API

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, cloud

I currently have an iOS app that allows users to create files and folders, and there's an option to toggle "iCloud" backup in the app settings. When enabled, the files and folders are moved from the local path to the iCloud path, creating a backup accessible across different devices.

Now, I'm looking to implement a similar feature in my Android app using the Google Drive API. However, I'm facing challenges as the Google Drive API relies on IDs for files and folders rather than paths, making it more complex than the iOS implementation.

I've explored the Google Drive API documentation, but it lacks detailed information on achieving this specific functionality (I'm sort of new to Android development). Any guidance or code examples on how to structure and implement this cloud backup feature in Android using the Google Drive API would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.